# How to prove 3NF?

Tags: proof, 3nf

I am trying really hard to spin my brain around how to prove 3NF. 
I actually have the answer, but if someone know this well enough to make me understand it, I would be very grateful. Ok, here it goes:

1. If R is in 3NF according to Definition 2, R must be in 3NF according to Definition1.
   Recall that if R is in 3NF according to Definition 1, then the following two conditions must be satisfied.

i) For R, we don’t have any transitive function dependency between a non-key
attribute and a key through some other non-key attribute.

ii) For R, we don’t have any partial function dependency between a non-key attribute
and a key.

Assume that R does not satisfy (i). Then, we must have a transitive FD: X → A, A → B, where X is a key, A and B are non-key attributes. But according to Definition 2, R does not have such kind of FDs. (That is, A must be a prime attribute or a super key.) Contradiction. So R must be satisfy (i).

Assume that R does not satisfy (ii). Then, we must have a subset S of a key X (S ⊂ X) such that there exists a non-key attribute A with S → A. However, according to Definition 2, S must be a super key. Contradiction. So R must satisfy (ii).
Therefore, R is in 3NF according to Definition 1.

2. If R is in 3NF according to Definition 1, R must be in 3NF according to Definition 2.

￼
Assume that R is not in 3NF according to Definition 2. Then, we must have a FD: X → A such that X is not a super key and A is not a prime attribute. Consider the a key X’ of R. We must have
X’ →X→A.
It is a transitive FD between the non-key attribute A and the key X’ through X. If X is a non-key attribute, then R is not in 3NF according to Definition 1. Contradiction. If X appears in X’, we have a partial FD. So R is not in 2NF, contradicting to Definition 1.

Comment: To prove that they are equivalent, that is :)

Comment: So what are Definitions 1 & 2?